# Is a square root of a unit of a quadratic field also a unit?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For example: $\,$In $\,$ $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]$, $\;\omega^3-\omega-1$ $\,$ is a unit. For: $\,$$\omega=\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}$ ; his Norm is 1. Then:$\,$Is $\,$$\,$  $\sqrt{\omega^3-\omega-1}$ $\,$ also a unit of$\,$ $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]$$\,$?$\,$ Thanks in advance

Comment: The norm is multiplicative…

Comment: there's no square root of $i$ in $\Bbb Z[i]$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: but $\Bbb Z[i]$ isn't a quadratic field, or is it?

Comment: @RobertLewis Make that $\mathbb Q(i)$, their point still stands.

Comment: @Wojowu:  seen! Cheers!

Comment: It's true JW Tanner. Thanks

Comment: This all being said, _if_ a unit in a field has a square root in that field, then the square root is also a unit, by multiplicativity of the norm.

Comment: Related but not exactly the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045533/is-sqrt1-sqrt2-a-unit-in-some-ring-of-algebraic-integers

Comment: Is $\omega^3-\omega-1$ even in $\mathbb Z[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]$?

Comment: Hi JW Tanner. 2 doesn't divide  $\omega^3-\omega-1$  because is a unit. Moreover, I later found that:  $\omega^3-\omega-1=(\omega^2+\omega)^2$ .  Then:  $\sqrt{\omega^3-\omega-1}=\omega^2+\omega$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expect that the square root of a unit will not be in the given field.

But if your unit $\zeta$ is root of the monic $\Bbb Z$-polynomial $f(X)$, then you see: first, that $\zeta^{1/2}$ is root of $f(X^2)$; second, that $\zeta^{1/2}$ is root of a monic $\Bbb Z$-polynomial, thus an algebraic integer; third, that since the constant coefficient of $f$ is $\pm1$, $\zeta^{1/2}$ is also a unit.